# How to show QuTiP Bloch sphere as onset figure on the bigger plot with other data?

Tags: python, qutip

Code:

```
b=qt.Bloch(axes=a)
pnt = [px[:],py[:],pz[:]]
b.add_points(pnt)
# b.fig = plt.subplot(326)
plt.title('Bloch sphere')
```

This code creates small onset figure, but it is empty.
[See screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpfeD.png)

Showing Bloch sphere as a separate figure works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Render function is necessary before show().
Arguments (fig and axes) must be assigned for both creating Bloch instance and calling render.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = subplot('211', projection='3d')
b = qt.Bloch(fig=fig, axes=ax)
b.render(fig=fig, axes=ax)
plt.show()
```